# Does Google back-up application settings?

Tags: backup, google-backup

In `Settings > Backup & reset` there is a "Back up my data" option under which it says "Back up app data...".

Does it really work?

Because I got into one of those "boot loops" and had to do a factory reset. After that I re-installed the apps I had previously installed, but the application settings were not restored by Google.

Do I need to do anything?

Answer (score 3):

Only apps that are coded to use the Google service will back-up and restore data. See this post for more information.

[Does the built-in Google app data backup work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49706/does-the-built-in-google-app-data-backup-work)